Is it possible to initialize a struct reference with an array?
Is it possible to do something like this?:
struct S {
  int length;
  char data[100];
};

class C {
  uint8_t buffer[10];
  S& s = buffer[0];
};

If I use pointer it compiles, but working with reference would be more convenient:
class C {
  uint8_t buffer[10];
  S* s = (S*)buffer;
};

In case you are wondering why one would do something like that, I have a struct similar to S above that is used to send and parse various data packets. Some actual packets have known limited lengths, so it does not make sense to allocate more space than necessary for them, by declaring member as simple S.
UPDATE:
It seems I did not explain my intentions clearly enough. Maybe a snippet of actual code may help.
typedef struct BP_Error_t {
    uint8_t cause;
    uint8_t error;
} BP_Error_t;

typedef struct BP_Upload_Rq_t {
    char    file[FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t chunk[MAX_FILE_CHUNK];
} BP_Upload_Rq_t;

typedef struct BusPacket_t {
    uint8_t source;
    uint8_t target;
    uint8_t packet_id;
    uint8_t length;
    union {
        BP_Error_t          error;
        BP_TPI_Poll_t       tpi_poll;
        BP_TPI_ACK_t        tpi_ack;
        BP_WiFi_Poll_t      wifi_poll;
        BP_WiFi_ACK_t       wifi_ack;
        BP_Erase_Rq_t       erase_rq;
        BP_Erase_Rsp_t      erase_rsp;
        BP_Upload_Rq_t      upload_rq;
        BP_Upload_Rsp_t     upload_rsp;
        BP_Download_Rq_t    download_rq;
        BP_Download_Rsp_t   download_rsp;
        BP_DFU_Rq_t         dfu_rq;
        BP_DFU_Rsp_t        dfu_rsp;
    };
} BusPacket_t;

As you can see I have a struct representing various data packets. The sizeof() of it will be defined by the longest union member, which is 240 bytes. Now, let's say I want to have ready to send error packet (which is only 6 bytes long) as a class member.
If I declare it as BusPacket_t I will waste a lot of memory for nothing. So I though that I can allocate a 6-byte array and then alias it as struct for easy access.

I'd use a member function that returns a reference to the buffer that has been cast to an S POD object.  Note that if the data types are not POD, I suspect you'd quickly end up in UB land.

Please fix missing semicolons. It's not clear what task you accomplish, why you want to cast char, one byte to 100+ bytes.

The pointer version is also simply UB. Conceptually what you want to do is not possible in the C++ object model.

The correct approach would be to apply std::start_lifetime_as on the buffer containing the packet to create an object of the correct type with the correct size and then using the pointer returned from it at the point-of-use. If code needs to be able to handle both types, then it should use a corresponding std::variant of the pointer types.

The problem seems to be that there shouldn't be a union in BusPacket_t. Instead there should be one BusPacket_X_t for each of the potential choices (probably as a template) and then (perhaps) BusPacket_t should be a union (or better std::variant) of them. Otherwise, even with the clarification, I can only repeat that the object model doesn't permit doing what you want and your current approach is in UB land.

@user17732522 yes, i thought about that. But the header fields will create an ambiguity for union. I'll see if I really need a union. It was done just for convenience of parsing incoming data (the packet_id field defines actual payload format and corresponding union member to be used)

@Maple There is no problem with the headers. If you make a union of the individual types you are still allowed to be inspect the header of any one of them via any of the union members because the header is a common initial sequence of standard layout types (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard-layout).

Note that if you're just writing C++, then the typedef is useless.
Otherwise, I would turn things around and declare the BusPacket_t first and then use that as a "header" in the other structs, like so:
struct BusPacket_t {
    uint8_t source;
    uint8_t target;
    uint8_t packet_id;
    uint8_t length;
};

struct BP_Error_t {
    BusPacket_t packet;
    uint8_t     cause;
    uint8_t     error;
};

struct BP_Upload_Rq_t {
    BusPacket_t packet;
    char        file[FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
    uint8_t     size;
    uint8_t     chunk[MAX_FILE_CHUNK];
};

...

Then the size of each struct is what's required by that struct and not the largest possible struct.
I would imagine that you'll need to read & write that data to places such as a network stream, so I would avoid using classes that can end up adding unwanted things to your struct. Otherwise, I would derive from the BusPacket_t class and benefit from its functions (and probably some virtual functions to get the total size of that packet).
class BusPacket_t {
public:
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
};

class BP_Error_t : public BusPacket_t {
public:
    virtual size_t size() const { return sizeof(BP_Error_t); }
};

But I think the sizeof() will include the size of the virtual table (for example). So probably not what you want...

To answer your question about the reference, here is how you would write it so it compiles:
struct S {
  int length;
  char data[100];
};

struct C {
  uint8_t buffer[10];
  S& s = *(S *)buffer;
};

To some extend, it will work as expected, except that this is UB since uint8_t buffer[10] may or may not represent an S object:

in your example, it does not since buffer is 10 bytes when sizeof(S) is likely 104 bytes
as far as I know, whether the size is a match, it is considered UB since you use a reinterpret_cast<>() (the (S *), also referred to as old cast, is a reinterpret_cast<>()).
buffer may or may not be properly aligned for an S object (although in most likelihood, it will be fine if at the start of a struct you allocate since allocated memory is properly aligned for all basic types). [see comments]

As shown in the comments, it is possible for force alignment using alignof(<type>), however, if you have many alignment requirements (i.e. need to match struct A, B, and C), it becomes rather complicated to handle, i.e. you have to find the most constraining alignment.


for buffer to represent an S it requires std::launder(), so we should at least use S& s = *std::launder((S *)buffer);—yet, as mentioned above, one of the rules of the std::launder() function is that buffer would need to represent an object x and since buffer is 10 bytes and S is 104, that is clearly false. [see comments]


It is UB already because no S object can possibly exist. For it to exist in the array the array would have to be at least as large as S. Even if the object existed, simply using the casted pointer and derferencing it would be UB. It would need to go through std::launder first.

Because buffer is not properly aligned for S, there is also in practice very much the possibility for unexpected behavior of resulting from this UB even if no access outside the bounds of the original arrays happen.

Instead of virtual functions a std::variant can be used and to obtain size one can do std::visit([](auto& typedPacket){ return sizeof(typedPacked); }, packet). Annoying is only that std::variant will hold its own type discriminator, while OP has it already embedded in the packet data. Writing specialized std::variant/std::visit for the packet type may be useful.

Accepted answer for providing compilable syntax for original question. The rest of the answer and the comments make me re-evaluate the whole approach. I'll probably use suggested header inclusion with "packed" attribute. Also, is there any difference between inclusion and inheriting the header, that I should be be aware of?

@user17732522 "Because buffer is not properly aligned for S" I have to use packed attribute for all those structs, to make sure no padding garbage goes on the bus. AFAIK it forces byte alignment on them. Would that not make them compatible with byte arrays, which should not have any alignment at all?

@Maple The problem is that the byte array must be aligned to the alignment requirement of S. You can never have a valid pointer to some type T in standard C++ that is not aligned to at least alignof(T). Packed attributes are compiler-specific extensions that work for a subset of architectures. Not all achitectures support unaligned access and when they do, they are typically (much) slower. Packed attributes also impose restrictions on how the structure may be used, depending on the compiler.

@Maple  For example, generally, no pointers or references to members of the struct may be passed around (because they would be misaligned). The correct thing to do is to write alignof(S) uint8_t buffer[10]; instead of uint8_t buffer[10]; to force the alignment requirements, regardless of whether or not S uses the packed attribute. (It doesn't resolve the other UB reasons though, of course.)

@user17732522 how about assigning an address of member of a struct to local struct pointer if all three (pointer, struct and member) defined with struct attribute((packed, aligned(1)))? Are these attributes preserved when struct is used as class member?

@Maple "to local struct pointer": What exactly do you mean? Of course all of this is going to be completely compiler-dependent. Assuming GCC: If at all what would be important is the aligned attribute on the pointed-to type in the pointer variable's type. However, it isn't even clear to me whether the aligned attribute on a typedef can be used to decrease alignment effectively. Even if it is supposed to be possible, my understanding is that there seem to be long-standing issues that cause pointers to always be assumed aligned for their type's normal alignment.

@Maple So I think forming (or at least dereferencing) any pointer to a member of a packed struct member will potentially be unsafe, especially on architectures with strict alignment requirements, but potentially also e.g. on x86 when the compiler decides to use some SSE instructions that require alignment. I am not sure whether GCC performs any actual optimizations that assume alignment of pointers aside from choosing the machine instructions accordingly. See e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51628 for discussion on all of the above.
